# Execute external application synchronously in electron app

Tags: node.js, async-await, electron, fetch, child-process

I'm building a electron app in which i have some dependencies of python( wrapped up as another exe).
Now i want to call that api synchronously, although i'm successful in calling it asynchronously

Asynchronous Code -

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
var executablePath = "dist/formflaskserver/formflaskserver.exe";
child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
if(err){
   console.error(err);
   return;
}

});
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4545/load/'+encodeURIComponent($("#jdata").val()))
.then(res => res.text())
.then(body => console.log(body));
```

Some tried things -

1. execFileSync - I'm getting multiple error while using "execFileSync", i think there are some sort of parameters which has to be passed but unable to figured out.
2. Put fetch in callback - no response

Comment: Please share the which error you are facing by using ```execFileSync```

Comment: basically, I think your path is wrong

Comment: ```path.join(__dirname, "dist/formflaskserver/formflaskserver.exe");```

Comment: @tpikachu thanks for the help, it's not the problem of the path as I'm able to call my flask Exe asynchronously but I was looking for a synchronous solution.

Comment: @tpikachu I don't know which parameter should be used as an argument for calling a Exe with execFileSync using electron

Comment: ```execFileSync``` first parament is filePath and second parameter is arguments that is needed at your formflaskserver.exe

Comment: If your formflaskserver.exe doesn't require any arguments then you can just keep this as null

Comment: The third parameter is execFileSync options. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfilesync_file_args_options

Comment: You should use ```spawn``` instead of ```execFileSync```